# Open an Image through specific app using PDF hyperlink

Tags: python, windows, image, pdf, hyperlink

I have used pymupdf, fitz to insert hyperlinks into a PDF that lets me open images when the hyperlinks are clicked. Is it possible to specify a certain application to open the images with or will they always be opened with the default image viewer of the operating system?

Comment: Specifying a specific application to open linked images is not possible through pymupdf alone. The behavior of opening the images is determined by the PDF viewer application and the system's default settings for file associations.

Comment: As @xFranko wrote: You probably use `LINK_LAUNCH` as the link kind. While you can put pretty much any string in "file" (like `viewer image.file`), the PDF reader will look for the existence of a file named `"viewer image.file"` and will refuse to do anything.

Comment: Yes, I believe PDF viewers like Adobe also do not let you open .exe files. Unless it is allowed through the Windows registry (which is definitely not recommended). So it's not possible to run a command line operation for .exe image viewers either.